# How can I change the apps script owner?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

The original owner created the spreadsheet and its bound script. That user has now transferred ownership of the spreadsheet to me so that I can manage the publishing going forward. However, when I try to publish, I get the following error:

> Only the owner of a script can publish the script as an add-on.

Why doesn't the ownership of the parent sheet propagate down to the script and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

If they already published it, the app is published under an account that isn't yours. Because you cannot delete a script from the Google Developer page, the ownership of THAT version cannot be erased, so it can't be changed. But, because the script is linked back to your document, it won't let you republish that script again, because it's already published by an owner who isn't you.

Unfortunately, you have to copy and paste the script into your own sheet and publish it yourself.

Comment: Well, that's sad. Thanks

Comment: I know... I had a similar problem. Good luck

Comment: Damn, this is problematic if a team needs to own an add-on.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020 (actually since 2019) you don't make updates to your add-on directly from the Scripts editor.

This is what you see if you select "Publish" and then "Deploy as Docs add-on"

[image]

- [To publish a new add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/editor-publish-overview)
- [To update an existing add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/update-editor-addons#update_published_add-on_code)

--

I saw this error and got stuck because I couldn't open the script logged in as the owner of the document. I also couldn't change the owner of the script. When I select File - Share, I see this: "An error occurred. The selected file cannot be shared at this time."

I managed to change the owner of the document associated with the script and then I was able to see the error in the screenshot above.

Using the Cloud Console you should be able to setup an organisation.